# Bulk Update from one table to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I tried the bulk update in order to copy values from uemte_id column in pp_terminal table to uemte_id column (null at start) in mm_chip table. These two tables have no columns in common.This is what I used:

```
declare
  type ue_tab is table of  
            pp_terminal.uemte_id%type;

 ue_name ue_tab;
  cursor c1 is select uemte_id from pp_terminal;

begin
 open c1;
fetch c1 bulk collect into ue_name;
 close c1;
 -- bulk insert
forall indx in ue_name.first..ue_name.last
   update mm_chip set uemte_id = ue_name(indx);

end;
/
```

And this is the error message I get:

```
Error report:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DPOWNERA.IX_AK7_MM_CHIP) violated
ORA-06512: at line 13
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

Do you see any obvious misstakes?

Comment: Yes, you're breaking a unique constraint when you're updating `mm_chip`. I'm assuming you have a constraint that includes `uemte_id`?

Comment: Yes I do, but I do not see how I'm breaking it since all uemte_ids in pp_terminal are unique and uemte_ids in mm_chip are null.

Comment: Jim Hudson has just given you a good explanation. As an extra note you don't commit or close your cursor in the PL/SQL block; though this may be just a copy and paste issue it's worth doing both if you're not.

Comment: How do you know which value from `pp_terminal` belongs in each row of `mm_chip` if they have no columns in common?

Comment: I'll keep in mind the cursor commit and close, thanks. 
I only need to copy uemte_id values to mm_chip. There is no relation between the rows.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that each value in `pp_terminal` should be assigned to a random row in `mm_chip` that hasn't already received a value?

Comment: @Allan See my comment to Jim's answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is:

- select a row from the first table
- update every row in the second table with that value
- select another row from the first table
- update every row in the second table with that value
- and so forth until the loop finishes

I'm guessing that's not what you really want to do. It's failing because you have a unique constraint so you're not allowed to have multiple rows in the second table with the same value.

Comment: I didn't see your answer Jim. You are right, what I wish to do is:

- select a row from the first table
- update a row in the second table with that value
- select another row from the first table
- update another row in the second table with that value
- and so forth until the loop finishes

Or if it is possible: select all rows in the first table and update all rows in the second table with those values.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to update each row of one table based on the value of an arbitrary row in a second table, without reusing any rows from the second table. It would perform better if you could do it entirely in SQL, but I couldn't come up with a way to do that.

```
CREATE TABLE test4 AS
   (SELECT     LEVEL AS cola, CAST(NULL AS number) AS colb
    FROM       DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100);

CREATE TABLE test5 AS
   (SELECT     100 + LEVEL AS colc
    FROM       DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 99);

DECLARE
   CURSOR cur_test4 IS
      SELECT     *
      FROM       test4
      FOR UPDATE ;
   CURSOR cur_test5 IS
      SELECT * FROM test5;
   r_test5 cur_test5%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_test5;

   FOR r_test4 IN cur_test4 LOOP
      FETCH cur_test5 INTO r_test5;

      IF cur_test5%NOTFOUND THEN
         EXIT;
      END IF;

      UPDATE test4
      SET    colb   = r_test5.colc
      WHERE  CURRENT OF cur_test4;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cur_test5;
END;
```

Comment: Works fine for my purposes, thanks! (So, I was missing a cursor for the table I was updating.)